# What is the correct name for Hyperparametrs XGBOOST in a Pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, xgboost

I'm working in a classification problem, and I'm using the Grisearch method for finding the optimal hyperparameters. However I'm using the architecture of a pipeline for build the same classification model changing only the classifier. The error for the xgboost is the string for the parameters. Do you have some advices ?

```
        elif method == "XGBoost":

            #classifier = Boosting
            classifier = XGBClassifier(random_state = 0, n_jobs = 4)

            parameters = {"xgb__max_depth":[3,4,5,6,7,9],
                          "xgb__gamma":[0, 0.1, 0.2],
                          "xgb__colsample_bytree":[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],                
                          "xgb__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100, 500],
                          "xgb__learning_rate": [0.1, 0.5, 1],
                          'xgb__min_child_weight': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

                    }


        print("Start PIPELINE !!!")

        # Add one transformers and two samplers in the pipeline object
        pipeline = make_pipeline(renn, smote_enn, classifier)
        #pipeline = make_pipeline(knn)
        print()
        print(" Starting Grid Search, with this method: " + method)
        print()


    #If it is not clear review the link from Stack
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370150/how-to-implement-smote-in-cross-validation-and-gridsearchcv

        scorers = {
                'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label="1"),
                'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label="1"),
                'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
                'f1_scorer': make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label="1")
            }

        random_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,  param_grid = parameters ,
                                           cv = kf,  scoring = scorers, refit = 'recall_score')
        gg = random_search.fit(X, y)
```

However I have obtained this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter xgb for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
steps=[('repeatededitednearestneighbours', RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours(kind_sel='all', max_iter=100, n_jobs=2,
n_neighbors=5, random_state=0, ratio=None,
return_indices=False, sampling_strategy='auto')), ('smoteenn', SMOTEENN(enn=None, random_state=0, ratio=None, ...
reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
silent=True, subsample=1))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the step in the pipeline is not `xgb` but rather the class name in low case (i.e. `xgbclassifier`). So either you use that name in `parameters` or use `Pipeline` directly instead of `make_pipeline` and set the step name as you wish, e.g. `xgb`